# How to import salesforce standard/custom object and fields into excel sheet

Tags: api, custom-object, import, object

I'm preparing the list of master objects and instead of me going through one by one is there a way I can import object name and fields into excel sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of apps available to do this. I have personally tried the first one and I think it will meet your requirement.

Salesforce Schema Lister (from http://sftoolkit.co/)
https://schemalister.herokuapp.com

Force.com Explorer 
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/ForceExplorer

Etherios EasyDescribe - Free MetaData Viewer/Extractor
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000018leZEAQ